# change font size in flex4 datagrid dynamically

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

how do i change the datagrid's font size on the click of a button. size will be an input from a text box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
datagrid.setStyle("fontSize", int(textBox.text));
```